# Simplifying Multiple Substitute Formulas in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I simplify this formula to delete all repeated - in Excel?

Cell A1: text---------------text-text---text

Cell A2: text----text--text---text

I need it to be:

Cell A1: text-text-text-text

Formula I am using:

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--","-"),"--","-"),"--","-"),"--","-")

I was wondering if there is a way with same SUBSTITUTE formula to do something like 4*SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--","-") so it makes the job 4 times without a huge formula.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in cell b1: `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"--","-")`
you can then copy this across to c1, d1, e1 etc. Each further cell to the right will have one less - than the previous. Add columns until all hyphens are dealt with.

This way if you add a new row where there are more hyphens than in previous rows, you can just make extra columns, instead of changing the formula which gets messy.

Answer (score 1):

A tiny trick for a single cell solution.  If **A1** does not contain any spaces, in **A2** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," "))," ","-")
```

This can handle any number of consecutive dashes:

[image]

If **A1** does contain some spaces, a slightly more complex formula will be required!

**EDIT#1:**

If **A1** contains spaces, they must first be "protected" with something like:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1))
```

and then, in the outer-most substitution, the "protection" must be removed.  The final formula is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1)),"-"," "))," ","-"),CHAR(1)," ")
```

I will admit that this is pretty ugly, but it can handle an unlimited number of dashes.

Comment: Hello, thanks. How is formula when containing spaces? Thanks

Comment: @Joao  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Hello Gary, I tried all formulas you said and all in here say has something missing...

Answer (score 0):

### If you think your needs might change, use a lookup table

The website *exceljet.com* had [a very good way of](https://exceljet.net/formula/find-and-replace-multiple-values) handling this by Dave Bruns.  This works very well when you'd like to see your corrections laid out in a table, and edit them or change them.

It avoids *hard coding* all the corrections into formulas, which can be hard to verify (and impossible when printed on paper).

It works by using the `INDEX` function.  Create a **lookup table**:

```
before    | after
--------- | ---------
APPLE     | ALICE
BANANA    | BOB
CHERRY    | CARL
KIWI      | KENNY
```

- Use `Insert:Table` to tell Excel it's a table, and let's name it `corrections`: [image]

Then in your main table, use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
J2,
INDEX(corrections[before],1),INDEX(corrections[after],1)),
INDEX(corrections[before],2),INDEX(corrections[after],2)),
INDEX(corrections[before],3),INDEX(corrections[after],3)),
INDEX(corrections[before],4),INDEX(corrections[after],4))
```

- Yes, you're allowed to have 'returns' (linefeeds) in a formula.  Excel ignores them, but they make it much easier to read.
- There's no magic in the numbers 1,2,3,4... they are the row numbers in the `corrections` table for the `INDEX` function.
- The number of rows (4) in the lookup table is the same as the number 4 in the formula.  If you need more rows, read on:

### Expand as necessary

If you need to add more rows to your `corrections` table, it's very easy. Just modify your replacement formula.  Let's say you want to go up to eight rows:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
J2,
INDEX(corrections[before],1),INDEX(corrections[after],1)),
INDEX(corrections[before],2),INDEX(corrections[after],2)),
INDEX(corrections[before],3),INDEX(corrections[after],3)),
INDEX(corrections[before],4),INDEX(corrections[after],4)),
INDEX(corrections[before],5),INDEX(corrections[after],5)),
INDEX(corrections[before],6),INDEX(corrections[after],6)),
INDEX(corrections[before],7),INDEX(corrections[after],7)),
INDEX(corrections[before],8),INDEX(corrections[after],8))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TEXTJOIN("_", TRUE, TEXTSPLIT("...", {"\";"/";":";"*";"?";"""";"<";">";"|";"."}))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).